# cannot log in by using password that has been hash

Tags: php

I'm trying to login into the account by using the md5 password. but the error keeps showing that invalid parameter number. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
<?php  

 include_once '../database.php';
 include_once 'reg_Customer.php';
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION["CustomerName"]))  
      {  
        header("location:index.php");
      }

 try  
 {  
       $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
      {  
           if(empty($_POST["CustomerName"]) || empty($_POST["CustomerPass"]))  
           {  
                $message = '<label>All fields are required</label>';  
           }  
           else  
           {  

                $query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE CustomerName = :CustomerName AND CustomerPass = ".md5(CustomerPass)."";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);  
                $stmt->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'CustomerName'     =>     $_POST["CustomerName"],  
                         md5('CustomerPass')     =>     $_POST["CustomerPass"] 
                     )  
                );  
                $count = $stmt->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                    
                    $_SESSION["CustomerName"] = $_POST["CustomerName"];  
                   
                  

                     header("location:index.php");  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     $message = '<label>Wrong Password</label>';  
                }  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 catch(PDOException $error)  
 {  
      $message = $error->getMessage();  
 }  
 ?>
```

the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match the number of tokens

Comment: Regardless of the actual error, you should throw this code away and start again: MD5 is a **really really insecure** function to use for password hashes; you might as well be storing them in plain text. Instead, generate a strong, salted hash with [password_hash](https://php.net/password_hash) and check the user's input against it using [password_verify](https://php.net/password_verify).

Comment: a correct approach imho should be to: store the password on the db with password_hash when the user registers. When he tries to login download the hashed password from the db and match it against the input password with password_verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually setting the value already when defining the query:

```
[...] AND CustomerPass = ".md5(CustomerPass)."";
```

It has to be `[...] AND CustomerPass = :CustomerPass`.

Also, in your array, you use the MD5 hash function on the key, not the value. It has to  be:

```
'CustomerPass'     =>     md5($_POST["CustomerPass"])
```

Other than that, don't use `md5` as IMSoP already stated. `password_hash` is your friend, or other hash functions such as `SHA2-512`.

Comment: Rolling your own hash with SHA2-512 is still a bad idea - data verification hashes are designed to be **fast**, but password hashes are designed to be **slow**, to combat brute force. password_hash and password_verify will use an appropriate algorithm, and manage the salt for you; I can't think of any reason *not* to use them.

Comment: Neither can I, it was just added to name a _more_ secure hash function, not _the most secure_ one. I still think SHA2-512 is doing a decent job - especially when forcing long(er) passwords. But yeah, in the wide array of hash functions available, functions like _bcrypt_ are a better fit for the task, no doubt.